# strict equality check for undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

I cant seem to figure this answer out so maybe you could help shed some light. In my defense, `undefined` is a message returned when a variable, key, value etc could not be found. A message should be a string? No?

```
let foo = [{id: 1, you: "me"}]
let undif = foo.find(i => i.he === 1)
if (typeof undif === "undefined") {
  console.log(undif) // not fired
}

if (typeof undif == undefined) {
  console.log(undif) // not fired
}

if (typeof undif == 'undefined') {
  console.log(undif) // fired!
}
```

Why cant I use `typeof undif === 'undefined`?

Comment: To start with, your `undif` will never be undefined. Array.find returns `item | null`. Check `undif == undefined` ot `undif === null`

Comment: @Rajesh My bad, I meant to use `find`

Comment: typeof always returns a string, so it cannot be `undefined`; it can only be `'undefined'`. You could simply check `if ( undif ) { .... }`

Comment: Ok but the question is, why I cant use `===` instead of `==`?

Comment: @Sylar you *can* use `if (undif === undefined)` the variable `undif` is undefined, not its "type". `typeof undefined` returns the string "undefined", try running: `console.log(typeof undif === "undefined")`

Comment: @Sylar `null !== undefined` Hence, you cannot use `===`. Update your condition to `=== null` and it should be fine

Comment: Probably a copy paste error but your if statements are missing `{`

Comment: `if (undif)` is absolutely enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your code had syntax errors (missing the opening braces after every `if`), but once those are fixed, the first and third are both fired.

```js
let foo = [{id: 1, you: "me"}]
let undif = foo.find(i => i.he === 1)
if (typeof undif === "undefined") {
  console.log('1', undif) // fired
}

if (typeof undif == undefined) {
  console.log('2', undif) // not fired
}

if (typeof undif == 'undefined') {
  console.log('3', undif) // fired!
}
```

Comment: Should you not close the question as a typographical mistake?

Comment: @Rajesh I don't know. OP claims that the third `if` _does_ evaluate, which wouldn't happen if the code were failing to run due to a syntax error. You're more than welcome to vote to close it, though.

Comment: It does not in my react component. I have to use `==`. Works in the browser console.

Comment: @Sylar Then please show us the code from your react component.

Comment: @JLRishe In that case, your answer does not add anything. OP is still stuck

Answer (score 0):

triple equals looks for both value and type;

hence `undefined === 'undefined'` will return false

for same reason your first case returns true

[This](https://codeburst.io/javascript-double-equals-vs-triple-equals-61d4ce5a121a) is a wonderful article on double equals and triple equals along with falsy value comparsion